# Unable to select IE8 popup window using selenium RC

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, popup, selenium-rc

I am trying to send commands to a popup window in IE8 with Selenium RC.

Currently, I am able to click on a button and open the popup window.

However, *I am unable to select the window to send commands.*

I have done extensive research on this subject for about a week and I believe this is strictly an IE issue. I have found some work-arounds; several blogs have instructed users to open up a blank window to "catch" the commands.

However, when I implement the code below, a blank window pops up and upon clicking the button that opens the pop up, a THIRD window opens and loads with the page I need.

Am I setting the target inaccurately? Please see below for selenium rc commands as well as the html source code of the page.

**Java Code**

```
selenium.runScript("selenium.browserbot.document.getElementByID(
              'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebGroupBox1_btnAddRequirement').target='popup'"
);

selenium.openWindow("", "popup");

///Click on Add Requirement button
selenium.click("id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebGroupBox1_btnAddRequirement");

try { 
  Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
selenium.selectWindow("popup");
```

**HTML for Add Requirement button**

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebGroupBox1_btnAddRequirement" 
       type="submit" 
       style="font-family:Arial,Times New Roman,Courier New;" 
       onclick="return validateProject();
                 WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new  
                  WebForm_PostBackOptions(
                             "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$WebGroupBox1$btnAddRequirement", 
                             "", 
                             true, 
                             "", 
                             "", 
                             false, 
                             false
                  )
                 )
                " 
       value="Add New Requirement" 
       name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$WebGroupBox1$btnAddRequirement"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WatiN (different I know), I had to send a combination of alt+tab and enter to deal with pop-up boxes.